# How to include javascript to my Express.js app which also using socket io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

This is countdown project, and for time sync i'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/timesync

**server.js**

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var timesyncServer = require('timesync/server');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/admin.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('success-connection')
  socket.on('chat message', msg => {
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });  
});

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.IO server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});

// handle timesync requests
app.use('/timesync', timesyncServer.requestHandler);
```

I tried a few methods, but did't work.
I got this error message:
*GET http://localhost:3000/script.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)*
**Here is my project:**
[File-strucure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xJv4.png)

Comment: Provide your script.js here

Comment: Nothing have in my script.js only console.log(1). I tried to include it like this <script src="script.js"></script> on my index.html page.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying serving to send static files. `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');`. You need to enable using static files in your express app. Place all your static files(html, css, images, videos) in one folder. You can name the folder `static`. Then add this middleware to your app

```
app.use("/static", express.static('./static/'));
```

This should be enough to serve static files.

Comment: Did not solved. I added your code end of server.js and when i want run my server i got this: app.use("/static", express.static('./static/'));
                   ^
ReferenceError: **express is not defined**
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\countdown-socket-express\server.js:28:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)......

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: It's still not working.